# Left align for Tilelist or List in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How to use the horizontal align property of TileList or List in flex?

I want to make an align left of my TileList with only 1 column.

I know I can use a simple List for that, but this is a requirement.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by using HorizontalCenter

Zee

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the style textAlign so in MXML you would just add the attribute `textAlign = "left"` in AS it would be `myTileList.setStyle("textAlign","left");`